# Most efficient way to convert string-time to time

Tags: python

I have to run about a million operations to do:

```
"Runtime": "01:12:00" --> datetime.time(1,12)
```

What would be the most performant way to do this? Right now I'm just doing a split on the semicolons, and the doing a `datetime.time(...)` --

```
s = '01:12:00'
h,m,s = [int(i) for i in s.split(':')
st = datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
```

Comment: "runtime" does not sound like `datetime.time()` at all.

Comment: I am slightly shocked that I have to explain this to someone who has asked more than a thousand questions on this site, but: You have given us only the absolute bare minimum of information to work with. You obviously have a working piece of code (which you didn't share), which is not fast enough (how fast is it then?), you also didn't share any real example input; so how are we to test this? Do you expect us to construct all this ourself? Even though you could have easily prepared this information for us?

Comment: Not to mention the function to do this is built into the datetime library and clearly documented.

Comment: [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) suggests that your approach is significantly faster than `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: Came across [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2rq6gk/ever_notice_that_strptime_is_sometimes_the/) on r/Python about the stdlib strptime bottleneck -- might be helpful to review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module you could test different implementations yourself:

```
import datetime
import re

PAT = re.compile('(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')
TSTR = "01:12:00"

def fun1():
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(TSTR, "%H:%M:%S")
    return dt

def fun2():
    h,m,s = [int(i) for i in TSTR.split(':')]
    dt = datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
    return dt

def fun3():
    mat = PAT.match(TSTR)
    dt = datetime.time(hour=int(mat.group(1)), minute=int(mat.group(2)), second=int(mat.group(3)))
    return dt

def fun4():
    h,m,s = int(TSTR[0:2]), int(TSTR[3:5]), int(TSTR[6:8])
    dt = datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
    return dt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    # Use the default repeat arguments: repeat=3, number=1000000
    print(min(timeit.repeat("fun1()", setup="from __main__ import fun1"))) # 15.5739
    print(min(timeit.repeat("fun2()", setup="from __main__ import fun2"))) #  3.4544
    print(min(timeit.repeat("fun3()", setup="from __main__ import fun3"))) #  4.1829
    print(min(timeit.repeat("fun4()", setup="from __main__ import fun4"))) #  2.8675
```

The fastest approach is in `fun4`.  Your `split` method is next, followed closely (surprisingly, imo) by the regex approach, and straggling far behind is the `strptime` method.

Comment: By default, `strptime` is a Python implementation (`_strptime` module), *not* the system's implementation, this is to provide better cross-platform compatibility, but this probably doesn't help speed... You can use the `ctypes` module to use the system's `strptme`, which may be (significantly) faster.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, do you think it's worth benchmarking this?

Comment: I have no idea what the speed difference would be; it's difficult to estimate this in my experience ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [48]: s = '"Runtime": "01:12:00"'

In [49]: dt.strptime(s, '"Runtime": "%H:%M:%S"')
Out[49]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 12)
```

Comment: While this is probably the most appropriate method for getting from a string to a datetime object, I can't upvote it, since the OP asked for the most efficient method and this is *considerably* slower than his approach.  It's error-prone, however, without question.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import time
>>> a='01:12:00'
>>> b=time.strptime(a,'%H:%M:%S') # use %I instead of %H if you use 12-hour clock
>>> b
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=12, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Then use `b.tm_hour`, `b.tm_min` and `b.tm_sec` to get hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed the performance of the regex method, the string.split to array method, and OP's method

It appears that split to array is faster than regex by about 38% and faster than OP's method by about 15%.

```
import time
import re
import datetime

timestring = "01:12:00"

# STRING.split method, stored temporarily in array
beforeMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
for i in range(10000):
    result = re.search(r"(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})", timestring).groups()
    theTime = datetime.time(int(result[0]), int(result[1]), int(result[2]))
afterMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print "Using Regex: " + str(afterMillis - beforeMillis) + "ms"

# regex method
beforeMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
for i in range(10000):
    result = timestring.split(":")
    theTime = datetime.time(int(result[0]), int(result[1]), int(result[2]))
afterMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print "Using Split: " + str(afterMillis - beforeMillis) + "ms"

# STRING.split method, stored temporarily in three variables
beforeMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
for i in range(10000):
    h,m,s = [int(i) for i in timestring.split(':')]
    theTime = datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
afterMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print "Using Split with 3 Variables: " + str(afterMillis - beforeMillis) + "ms"
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
Using Regex: 52ms
Using Split: 34ms
Using Split with 3 Variables: 44ms
```

I don't think you'll find a much faster method than storing the split string in an array.

Storing the array temporarily is (a bit) faster than in three variables for a good reason: No further memory has to be used, and the compiler can probably optimize this easier.

All other answers (except for the one recommending regex) also fail to use datetime.time.

I recommend that you don't use the built-in `time` object for this purpose as it represents a unix time (seconds since Jan 1 1970), not a time of day.